# Complete proof output in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

If Isabelle did not find a proof for a lemma, is it possible to output everything that was done by all the proof methods that were employed in order to arrive at the subgoals, at which they couldn't proceed any further  ? This would help me see, at which avenues they got stuck, which then would help me to point them in the right direction.

(And also for completed proofs I would find it interesting to have a complete proof log that shows all the elementary inferences that were performed to proof some lemma.)

Answer (score 1):

This question sounds similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154106/error-message-in-isabelle-hol/42154618#42154618), which I answered a few days ago. Parts of that answer also apply here. Anyway, to answer this question specifically:

Not really. For most basic proof methods (`rule` et al., `intro`, `fact`, `cases`, `induct`) it is relatively straightforward what they do and when they fail, it is pretty much always because the rule they tried to apply does not unify with the goals/premises that they are given. (or they don't know which rule to apply in the first place)

You were probably thinking more of more automatic tactics like `blast`, `force`, `simp`, and `auto`. Most of them (`blast`, `force`, `fastforce`, `fast`, `metis`, `meson`, `best`, etc.) are ‘all-or-nothing’: They either solve the subgoal or they do nothing at all. It is therefore a bit tricky to find out where they get stuck and usually people use `auto` for this kind of exploration: You apply `auto`, look at the remaining subgoals, and think about what facts/parameters you could add in order to break down those more.

The situation with `simp` is similar, except that it does less than `auto`. `simp` is the simplifier, which uses term rewriting, custom rewriting procedures called simprocs, certain solvers (e.g. for linear arithmetic), and a few other convenient things like splitters to get rid of `if` expressions. `auto` is basically `simp` combined with classical reasoning, which makes it a lot more powerful than `simp`, but also less predictable. (and occasionally, `auto` does too much and thereby turns a provable goal into an unprovable goal)

There are some tracing tools (e.g. the simplifier trace, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018023/how-to-enable-tracing-in-isabelle-jedit)). I thought there also was a way to trace classical reasoning, but I cannot seem to find it anymore; perhaps I was mistaken. In any case, tracing tools can sometimes help to explain unexpected behaviour, but I don't think they are the kind of thing you want to use here. The better approach is to understand what kinds of things these methods try, and then when `simp` or `auto` returns a subgoal, you can look at those and determine what you would have expected `simp` and `auto` to do next and why it didn't do that (usually because of some missing fact) and fix it.